# Ajax Call fails because of number of arguments

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

Ajax Call to msgcall method:

```
PopAjaxPost('mesaj/popup/msgcall/' + i + '/' + $('input#mesajkategori').val(), mysarr, function (data) {
        if (data.Durum == '1') {
            $wrapper.html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="all">Mesaj</a><div class="preview"><div class="block"><strong>Gönderen:</strong>'
                + data.Data.Mesaj.Gonderen + '<br /><p>Sayın <strong>' + data.Data.Mesaj.Alici + '</strong></p><p>'
                + data.Data.Mesaj.Mesaj + '</p></div>' + (data.Data.Mesaj.SecenekId > 1 && !giden ? ('<input type="submit" value="Cevapla" onclick="mesajcevapla('
                + data.Data.Mesaj.MesajId + ');return false;" style="margin-bottom: 8px;">') : '') + '</div>');
        }
        else {
        }
    });
```

Here is msgcall method with three arguments:

```
[HttpPost]
[AjaxException]
[UserFilter]
public ActionResult MsgCall(string id, string pid, MsgHire model)
{
     ....
}
```

It does not invoke the msgcall method with the supplied arguments. If I remove the `+ i + '/'`, it invokes the msgcall method. What am I doing wrong?

From Route.config:

```
routes.MapRoute("MesajPopup", "mesaj/popup/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Mesaj", action = "Liste", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
routes.MapRoute("Mesaj", "mesaj/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Mesaj", action = "Liste", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: is there url configuration for `pid`? I mean In your route config, did you define an url routing like this : `mesaj/popup/msgcall/id/pid` ?

Comment: I've edited the answer. How should I modify routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configuration for additional parameter named `pid`, so you should define a maproute for this parameter.

Add something like this line:

```
routes.MapRoute("Msg_Call", "mesaj/popup/{action}/{id}/{pid}",
    new { 
        controller = "Mesaj", 
        action = "Liste", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional,  
        pid = UrlParameter.Optional 
});
```

Comment: don't we need to include pid like "mesaj/popup/{action}/{id}{pid}"?

Comment: Working as expected now. Sağol dostum!!